# A module without a basis

Tags: modules

It is well known that every vector space have a basis, after studying module theory I read in Wikipidia that not all modules have a basis.

Can someone please give an example of a module without a basis ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take $M = \mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ over $\mathbb Z$ for $n > 1$.

More generally, let $G$ be a finite abelian group, $|G|=n$. Let $g \in G$. Then $ng = 0$. By definition, a free module $M$ over a ring $R$ is a module with a basis. A basis of a module $M$ is a subset $B \subset M$ such that it is linearly independent and you can write every $m \in M$ as a finite linear combination of elements in $B$ (with coefficients in $R$).

If you choose $R = \mathbb Z$ and $G$ a finite abelian of order $n$, then for every finite linear combination of elements of $G$ you can get $0$ hence no subset of $G$ can be a basis hence $M = G$ cannot be free.

Answer (score 28):

Many answers! ${\mathbb{Q}}$ is a module over ${\mathbb{Z}}$, and has no basis. Indeed, if a ring $R$ is not a field, then it has a module that has no basis: let $I$ be a proper ideal of $R$ which is different from $\{0\}$. Then $R/I$ is a module that has no basis.

Comment: Sorry if this is trivial, but,Isn't the set  R/I itself a basis ?

Comment: No, @MSIS . You seem to be suggesting that if $M$ is an $R$-module, then $M$ is a basis (of itself).

Comment: Does $\mathbb R$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module have a basis?

Comment: No, @WillG , supposing that $B$ is such a basis, let $b\in B$, and look at $\frac12b$. This animal has no expression as a (finite) $\Bbb Z$-linear combination of elements of $B$.

Answer (score 9):

With modules, it is often useful to consider the slightly more general notion of "independent set":

**Definition.** Let $M$ be an $R$-module. We say that $m_1,\ldots,m_r\in M$ are "independent" if and only if for all $a_i\in R$, if $a_1m_1+\cdots+a_rm_r=0$, then $a_im_i=0$ for all $i$.

(This is weaker than "$R$-linearly independent": for example, $\{1+n\mathbb{Z}\}$ would be an independent set of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, but not linearly independent).

Even with this weaker notion, it is not true that every module over a ring has independent spanning sets.

For example, $\mathbb{Q}$ does not have an independent spanning set over $\mathbb{Z}$, since any finitely generated subgroup is cyclic, hence not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, and any subset with at least two elements is not independent (given $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$, take $bc(\frac{a}{b})-ad(\frac{c}{d})$, which equals zero though the separate summands do not).

Or consider any domain that is not a principal ideal ring, and let $I$ be an ideal that is not principal. Any two nonzero elements of $I$ are not independent (if $a,b\in I$, then $ba-ab=0$, but $ab\neq0$), so the only independent subsets of $I$ are the empty set and singletons, but $I$ is not generated by a single element because $I$ is not principal. For instance, take $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ in $\mathbb{Z}[1+\sqrt{-5}]$.

Comment: @MSIS That's not true even in vector spaces, which are modules over fields. $M$ always has a zero, so it is never linearly independent in *any* sense. It cannot be a basis. Yes, you are utterly lost. I suggest you do a thorough review first.

Comment: What if we *define* a linearly independent set to be a set such that no proper subset generates it. Then can we give an example of a module without a basis?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku: First, that's a **terrible** definition of "linearly independent"; second, that already has a name, it's called a "minimal generating set". As for an example, $\mathbb{Q}$ does not have a minimal generating set as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: Over vector spaces it is equivalent, so why is it terrible?

Comment: There are linearly independent sets that don’t generate, but that’s not what I said. I suggested we define a linearly independent set to be a set such that no proper subset generates it, which does seem to be equivalent in the context of vector spaces… Under my proposal the sets you mention do seem to be linearly independent.

Comment: Perhaps I was being unclear but I meant to define a linearly independent set as a set $B$, such that there is no proper subset of $B$ whose span contains $B$.

Comment: In the context of modules the usual def of linearly independent and this one are not equivalent, but in the context of vector spaces they seem to be….

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku Oh, dear; I missed the "it", so I apologize. It's not a "terrible" definition, but it is not a very useful one. Your definition is that a set $X$ is "linearly independent" if and only if it is a minimal spanning set of $\mathrm{span}(X)$. Again, you are trying to define an intrinsic property using an extrinsic definition that already has a name;  and $\mathbb{Q}$ does not have minimal spanning sets, so it does not have a "basis" under your notion, because that notion is just "minimal spanning set".

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku The definition also does not have the properties you might expect: if $X$ is l.i. under your notion, and $a\notin\mathrm{span}(X)$, it may still be the case that $X\cup\{a\}$ is not linearly independent: e.g., $X=\{2\}$ and $a=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules; so in general you cannot prove the existence of maximal "linearly independent" sets under your notion for modules.

Comment: Thanks very much, I was not familiar with the name minimal generating set in the context of modules.

Answer (score 6):

Another example, extracted from Musili's *Introduction to Rings and Modules*:

> Any abelian group $M$ which has a nontrivial element of finite order
>   cannot be free as a module over $\mathbb Z$.

In fact, say $B$ is a basis for $M$ over $\mathbb Z$. Let $a\in M\backslash\{0\}$ be such that $|a|=n$. Note that $n>1$. We have $$a=z_1b_1+z_2b_2+...+z_mb_m$$ for some $z_i\in \mathbb Z$ and $b_i\in B$, with $i=1,2,...,m$. Then, $$0=na=nz_1b_1+nz_2b_2+...+nz_mb_m.$$ By linearity of $B$, $$z_1=z_2=...=z_m=0 \Rightarrow a=0,$$ a contradiction. In particular,

> Any finite abelian group is not free as a module over $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{Q}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module (abelian group). If $p$ and $q$ are nonzero rational numbers, there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $px+qy=0$

Comment: Can you say why ?

Comment: What don't you understand, or is it clear now?

Comment: Why such $x,y$ exist and how can we prove that $\langle p,q \rangle \neq \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @Belgi: Because the subgroup generated by $p$ and $q$ cannot contain any rational whose denominator is greater than the product of the denominators of $p$ and $q$.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ exist because we can multiply $p$ and $q$ each by some integer to clear denominators, and then multiply the resulting numbers by each other (so that they are now the same), and finally change the sign on one of the two numbers in question.