# Ex. of a finitely generated module without a finite basis.

Tags: modules

I am working my way through *Linear Algebra - Hoffman and Kunze*. There is a very brief introduction to *Modules* in the chapter on *Determinants*. The authors state "..a module  may be finitely  generated  without  having a finite  basis.". I am looking for an example for such a module.

I am not familiar with Group/Ring theory (although a know the basic definitions), so the examples else where are taking too long to understand.

For ex. [A module without a basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137442/a-module-without-a-basis) forces me to go get an understanding of *subgroupgs, cyclic groups, factor groups*.

Comment: It's funny because on page 165, they say "We repeat that a module may be ..." but they never actually said it before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb Z_n$ as a $\mathbb Z$ module.

Comment: Ok. Annihilator of $\mathbb Z_n$ contains n. Thus it has no independent subset, let alone a basis. Thank you.