# Modules with no basis?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I was just reading a bit about modules on wikipedia, which, as I understood it, are generalizations of vector spaces.

I read there exists some modules that do not have a basis, and I couldn't think of an example or why this happens (vs vector spaces: they all have some basis).

Could someone explain this?

Comment: Any module that has a basis is called a *free* module, and these are the modules that are closest to vector spaces.  To find a module that isn't free, think of modules where every element can be zeroed by an element in the ring.  Then, no non-empty set can be a basis since we can have a nontrivial linear combination where we annihilate one of the elements.

Comment: By "every element can be zeroed by an element in the ring" you mean a ring where every element is a zero divisor?

Comment: possible duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137442/a-module-without-a-basis

Comment: Not exactly.  Every module, $M$, is associated with a ring $R$ where $R$ acts on $M$.  Think of a module, $M$, and a ring $R$ so that for every $m \in M$, $\exists~r \in R$ with $r \neq 0$ and $rm = 0$.

Comment: @NikosM. Hmm, I'm also asking why does this happen, not just for an example.

Comment: Note: not every vector space has a basis, unless you assume the axiom of choice.

Comment: A basis $B$ is a subset of a module $M$ which (1) spans $M$ (every module trivially has a spanning set) (2) is linearly independent (this is where modules fail to have a basis).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. Why does it not have a basis?

Comment: Hmm wouldn't $\{1\}$ be a basis?

Comment: Because a nontrivial linear combination of $\{1\}$ yields $0$.

Comment: $\{1\}$ is a generating set. However, it fails the linearly independent condition.

Answer (score 8):

Another example that you already knew: $\Bbb Q$ as a $\Bbb Z$-module.

Comment: I don't see why this doesn't have a basis, could you elaborate?

Comment: Gladly. Any two elements are $\Bbb Z$-linearly dependent; therefore a basis, if any there were, would have at most one element. But a single element does not generate $\Bbb Q$ as a $\Bbb Z$-module.

Comment: I see! Given $\frac a b, \frac c d \in \Bbb Q$ then $(bc)\frac a b+ (-ad)\frac c d=0;\, bc, -ad\in \Bbb Z$, for $bc,-ad$ not necesarilly 0, right?  How do you show that a single element can't generate $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: For that, I’d ask you to look at the picture. But if $\{a/b\}$ is your basis, then $a/2b$ is not in the $\Bbb Z$-span.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over the example regarding the pair $(M,\varphi)$ with $M$ being a $K$-Vectorspace and $\varphi\in\text{End}_K(M)$ and the corresponding $K[X]-$Module $M$.

If we choose a family $(x_n)$, who might be a linear independend family:

$$f(X)_0*x_0+f_1(X)*x_1+...+f_n(X)*x_n=0$$ then by choosing the local minimal polynomial of $x_i$ as $f_i(X)$ regarding $\varphi$, we get:

$$f_i(\varphi)(x_i)=0,\forall i\in\lbrace0,...,n\rbrace$$

concluding the family is linear dependend and especially no basis.

Please correct me if I am wrong.